# How can I compress an NBT with gzip?

Tags: c#, .net, minecraft

I want to get a NBT file, decompress it, modify it, and then re-compress it. The only problem is re-compressing. Unlike just using GZipStream and calling it a day, Minecraft (and standalone NBT editors) can't read it.

```cs
public static void PatchNBT()
{
    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"level.temp"); // Reads all bytes of the uncompressed NBT
    var GetDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "level.dat");
    Console.WriteLine(GetDirectory);
    Console.ReadKey();
    if (File.Exists("level.dat"))
    {
        File.Move("level.dat", "level.bak");
    }
    Task.WaitAll();

    File.WriteAllBytes(GetDirectory, CompressGZip(data));
}


static byte[] CompressGZip(byte[] raw)
{
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
        }
        return memory.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: you're modifying minecraft with .net? may I ask you how?

Comment: @JoãoVítorCosta I uncompressed it with Gzip, modified what I wanted, and now i'm stuck here.

Comment: what you're doing is illegal as it breaks Mojang's EULA, you should be using a supported modding framework such as Forge or Fabric
using said frameworks also make modding easier as they provide the proper infrastructure

Comment: @JoãoVítorCosta In that case, the specific editors are violating EULA too. And Forge or Fabric makes actual mods in Java, and this isn't the case for me and don't want it to be.

Comment: good luck then, but nbt isn't a stantard format, I believe it is only used by minecraft, and since minecraft is closed source you will find very little documentation on the format